# CREATE DATABASE - Error 1604

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I tried to create Database with:

`CREATE DATABASE 'mynewdb';`

and got:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''mynewdb'' at line 1

Why? What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quotes:

```
CREATE DATABASE mynewdb;
```

Comment: Many Thanks ThoriumBR!

Comment: If the answer helped, please upvote it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove your quotes or use backticks such:

```
CREATE DATABASE mynewdb;
```

or

```
CREATE DATABASE `mynewdb`;
```

---

Backticks are to be used for database, table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters beyond a limited set (see below) It is often recommended to avoid using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible, avoiding the quoting issue.

---

Here a very good answer [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql).

Comment: If you believe that the current question already has already been answered by another question here on O, then pls mark it as a duplicate, do not answer!